# Python26, Win32, ZBar - ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.6 (x86) and tried to install the ZBar module.

I downloaded the current version of ZBar (Win32-Installer):
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html

and the current version of the module on PyPi:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar

ZBar (prompt and webcam) works fine but as soon as I try to import zbar in Python, the following error raises:

```
import zbar
ImportError: DLL load failed
```

This happens when I try it with the binary windows installer of the module but I also tried using the `setup.py` which always exits with:

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'zbar' extension
error: None
```

Thank you,
Michael

EDIT: I also tried to troubleshoot the `Lib/site-packages/zbar.pyd` with Dependency Walker and it raised `libzbar-0.dll` and `python26.dll` to be missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the path to `libzbar-0.dll` to your system `PATH` so Windows can find it when `zbar.pyd` is loaded.

Edit: I installed the application and Python library. Here's how to make it work without changing your `PATH` through the control panel system configuration:

```
>>> zbar_path = os.path.join(os.environ['ProgramFiles'], 'zbar', 'bin')
>>> os.environ['PATH'] = "{0};{1}".format(os.environ['PATH'], zbar_path)

>>> import zbar
>>> zbar.version()
(0, 10)
```

Comment: @DrBwts, you'll have to do the work to solve it yourself. Use dumpbin to verify the dependencies of zbar.pyd. Verify that `os.listdir(os.path.join(os.environ['ProgramFiles'], 'zbar', 'bin'))` contains the dependent zbar DLL, e.g. libzbar-0.dll. Investigate the dependencies of the dependent DLLs, and so on. Learn to use a native debugger (not Python -- something like windbg or cdb) and walk through the import with loader snaps enabled.