# Python Zbar DLL load fail

Tags: python, dll, importerror, zbar

Firstly, I am aware of this [similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775339/python26-win32-zbar-importerror-dll-load-failed) but my problem is slightly different and the answer in that question did not solve my problem. So, I am creating a new post here.

I have downloaded **Zbar Installler** from *http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html* and managed to successfully(no error message) installed.

But, when i run the following script,

```
import zbar
from PIL import Image

# create a reader
scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()

# configure the reader
scanner.parse_config('enable')

# obtain image data
pil = Image.open('zbartest2.png').convert('L')
width, height = pil.size
raw = pil.tostring()

# wrap image data
image = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', raw)

# scan the image for barcodes
scanner.scan(image)

# extract results
for symbol in image:
    # do something useful with results
    print 'decoded', symbol.type, 'symbol', '"%s"' % symbol.data

# clean up
del(image)
```

It give me the error message saying that DLL load fail.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\Profiles\e492507\Desktop\barcode reader\test.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import zbar ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

but unlike the similar SO question i mentioned above, when i type this in the python IDLE shell, it works without any problem.

```
import zbar
zbar.version()
```

> (0, 10)

What is causing the problem and how do i fix it?

FYI: I am using Python 2.7.3 on windows Xp pro 32 bits

**UPDATE: 1**

I found out that if i copy the script and image into python directory `C:\Python27\` it works fine without any problem.

However, as soon as i move the script and image into other places, i got the same error message i posted above.

How should i fix this so that i can execute my script anywhere in my computer as long as the barcode image is available?

**UPDATE: 2** ***(JUST FOR INFO: NOT DIRECTLY RELATED TO THE QUESTION)***

I am not able to solve this problem using all the methods i have discovered so far.So, i am coming out with my own silly solution.

I am going to use a simple table drawn by `reportlab` instead of `Barcodes` and color the cells accordingly ( black for 1 and white for 0) to represents the numbers in binary.

So, number 69 will be something like this

[image]

Then, i can use `PIL` to detect the black and white squares and covert it back into binary then to decimal. FYI, i am only dealing with the decimal numbers. No alphabets nor other stuffs. I know this is pretty silly but desperate times call for desperate measures :P

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like it's working when the dependent DLL's are somewhere in your `PATH` and it breaks when you move them elsewhere. The error is specifically saying that it can't load the DLL (or one of its dependencies) so I don't think this is a problem related to the documented instability on Windows systems.

To eliminate this as a possibility, try the following:

1. Right-click **My Computer**, and then click **Properties**.
2. Click the **Advanced** tab.
3. Click **Environment variables**.
4. Locate and select the `PATH` entry and then click **Edit**.

In the dialog, where it says **Variable value**, add a semi-colon and then the path to the folder where `libzbar-0.dll` has been installed.

So, if `libzbar-0.dll` is in, say, `C:\ZBar\Bin` and your existing `PATH` value is :

`C:\folder1;C:\folder2;C:\some other folder`

Then change the variable value to :

`C:\folder1;C:\folder2;C:\some other folder;C:\ZBar\Bin`

Then click **OK** to save all of the changes and - for overkill - reboot. This is because most applications only read environment variables when they first start and it's sometimes confusing if you're not sure whether an application *really* restarted or was just minimised, for example.

Now see if you can run the Python script from other folders.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows version of`zbar`you installed (`zbar-0.10-setup.exe`) includes "*only command line programs*" as stated in its`README.windows`file. It also mentions that "The current (0.10) release of ZBar only comes with command line programs" in the **Running ZBar** section of the [Windows Installation Guide](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/zbar/index.php?title=Windows_Installation_Guide#Running_ZBar).

In the **Windows Installer** section of the [ZBar bar code reader - Download](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html) page it says:
    "Note that the Windows port is in an unstable, testing phase."

In other words, it's not yet consider usable from the Windows version of the Python interpreter.

Comment: I am able to run the same exact script on my `windows 8` pc using the same `zbar` installer with the same python version. Yet, i can't seems to make it work on my `windows xp` machine.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve .dll error, need to install C++ dependency, click below link and download:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784